# Fragments startActivityForResult always return resultCode 0 and intent null on callback onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I searched all over and there are similar posts about it, but can't find a solution!

My situation is I have an Activity A that holds a `fragment`, and from that `fragment` I want to start a new `Activity` B that should return some values to the `fragment`.

On the `fragment`

```
startActivityForResult(mapIntent, ConstantsUtils.TOMAP_REQUEST_CODE);
```

On the `Activity` B, to return the data

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra(SerializationConstants.isSearchSaved, mAbItemsShown.ordinal());
setResult (ConstantsUtils.SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, returnIntent);
finish();
```

On the fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

switch (requestCode) {

    case ConstantsUtils.TOMAP_REQUEST_CODE:

            if (resultCode == ConstantsUtils.SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE) {
              //do some stuff 
            }
    }
}
```

`onActivityResult` from the `fragment` is successfully called, with the right `requestCode` but `resultCode` is always 0 and intent is always `null`.

I have no other `onActivityResult` implementation under `Activity` A.

In fact, I also try starting the `activity` from the `fragment` with 
`getActivity().startActivityForResult(mapIntent, ConstantsUtils.TOMAP_REQUEST_CODE);`
and implementing `onActivityResult` on `Activity` A but it happens the same, right `requestCode` but wrong `resultCode` and `intent`.

I'm using `Sherlock Action Bar` so my `fragment` is a `SherlockListFragment` so I'm using the `support library (r18)`.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what your `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);` for. It is not necessary, in my opinion. Also, your request_code need to be >= 0, as it mention [here][doc][doc]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: super is not neccessary, i was just trying to see if the problem was because of it, but same result if I don't put it. The constant SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE has a value of 1, but the same happens with Activity.RESULT_OK

Comment: Looks like you are calling `finish()` somewhere else in ActivityB. Calling `finish()` without setting the result code and result data would result in exactly the behaviour that you are describing. Either that or ActivityB is crashing, that would do the same thing.

Comment: Then I have to advise you to check the Activity A, in `onStart()` or `onResume` part. If you create a new instances of the fragment in which you called `startActivityForResult`, it would be the problem. Normally, Android will automatically restore the previous state when you activity B call `finish()`. So I you create another fragment instance manually, it will replace the one who get the returned Intent.

Answer (score 16):

Result code 0 is `RESULT_CANCELLED`.

```
The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.
```

Also the common reason of getting this code is a launching an activity in a new task (check your intent and manifest for flags, which lead to the start of a new task).

Also if you have a parent activity, you should set result code of it instead of set result code of its child (try to `getParent` and if it is not null, than set result code of it).

Comment: I checked and I don't have any special flag in the manifest or when creating the intent. And the value of getParent inside the ActivityB (the one that does the setResult) is null

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The problem for me was that I had launchMode="singleTask" in my manifest.

Comment: @elimirks can you please explain me how you solved your problem? I need to have `launchMode="singleTask"` but I still like to start a new activity.

Comment: @mariosangiorgio the singleTask launch mode is meant for only stand alone activities.

Answer (score 8):

I spent some time to find out the reason. My mistake was put `super.onBackPressed()` in the `onBackPress()` method.

I called `finish()` in the method. But I think `super.onBackPressed()` will call the `finish()` automatically so you will get **resultCode 0** always. 
So just remove the `super.onBackPressed()` line in the `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this comment safe me! thank you :)

Comment: You dont need to remove super.onBackPressed(), just put setResult() code before super.onBackPressed()