# onActivityResult executing twice

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

From **HomeActivity** Im trying to get a result from **CreateProfileActivity**. Here what i do to start the activity

```
Intent createProfile = new Intent(this, CreatePreacherActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(createProfile, 1);
```

Here the implementation of `onActivityResult` method in **HomeActivity**:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 1)
        {

            Log.d("DEV","HomeActivity is reciving data");
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                // this code here execute at the second call
                // but why there are two calls when i just call setResult once???

                User user = new User();

                String[] userInfo = data.getStringArrayExtra("preacher");

                //parsing and saving and database code...

                Log.d("DEV","HomeActivity data received->"+user);

                CurrentUser.set(this, user);
                fillCurrentUserInforms();
            }

            // if while searching for the preacher list
            // and none was found on database. Then tell the user
            // to create a new profile
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                Intent createPreacherIntent = new Intent( this, CreatePreacherActivity.class );
                startActivityForResult(createPreacherIntent,1);
            }
        }
```

When im done and press **save** in `CreateProfileActivity` here is what I do to send the data back to **HomeActivity**:

```
**private void createProfile()
{
   // some parsing and inserting the new data code..
    User u = new User();
    u.setName(newPreacher.getName());
    u.setLastName(newPreacher.getLastName());
    u.setId(newPreacher.getId());
    u.setSex(newPreacher.getSex());
    CurrentUser.set(this,u);
    if (getParent() == null)
    {
        setResult(RESULT_OK,createPreacherDataIntent(newPreacher));
    }
    else
    {
        getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK,createPreacherDataIntent(newPreacher));
    }
    Log.d("DEV","Exiting from CreatePreacherActivity");
    finish();
}**
```

The setResult method is call one once on `CreateProfileActivity` but for some unknown reason when the data get to `HomeActivity.onActivityResult` method, get execute **twice**. The first result with the `requestCode = 0` and the second one with `requestCode  = 1`. After that,  `HomeActivity.onActivityResult` gets execute, **the CreateProfileActivity apears again** since the first call the requestCode was 0.

**Why then is onActivityResult executing twice??**

**What is 0 on the first call and then 1 on the second??**

Notes: I've read the following question to see if im doing something wrong but i can see it:

[Android onActivityResult is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510280/android-onactivityresult-is-always-0)

[fragments startActivityForResult always return resultCode 0 and intent null on callback onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512264/fragments-startactivityforresult-always-return-resultcode-0-and-intent-null-on-c)

[And more..](https://www.google.com.do/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=resultcode%200%20android)

UPDATE:

here my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jwutils.einers.informedeserviciotj" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="Inform de Servicio" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.inform.InformEditableActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.preacher.CreatePreacherActivity"
            android:label="Crear publicador"/>

        <activity android:name=".Activities.preacher.PreachersListActivity"
            android:label="Usuarios" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show us your manifest? Have you set `singleTask` on it?

Comment: @PedroOliveira take a look now. And if that is the error. How can i fix it??

Comment: @Misters Can you try to remove "this" from " CurrentUser.set(this,u);". It is looks like "CreateProfileActivity" activity's context is going back to onActivityResult after it finished.

Comment: @kozaxinan the **this** keyword pass as parameters is to **only access to the database** and nothing more. Its a static class that save in memory some data

Comment: @Misters When do you call "Intent createProfile = new Intent(this, CreatePreacherActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(createProfile, 1);"? In which state of activity?

Comment: @kozaxinan **onCreate()**, after a condition if there is a user logged in

Comment: Can you try it in onResume?

Comment: Ok, let me try. I'll text back

Comment: @kozaxinan it worked perfectly! You Can post a solution of your own  and i will acept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64086/discussion-between-kozaxinan-and-misters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try calling this in onResume() instead of onCreate();

```
Intent createProfile = new Intent(this, CreatePreacherActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(createProfile, 1);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), it say "You will receive this call immediately before onResume() when your activity is re-starting." I beleive that the first call of onActivityResult() with result code "0" is triggered when your first activity try to resume.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove**

**`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`**

from your activity's onActivityResult method.