# OnActivityResult getting called twice in Android

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I used this code to launch an activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneTimeActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra(Constants.HOST_KEY, host);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```

And for some reason my OnActivityResult() is called twice. Once when I first call startActivityForResult and once when the result actually ends. What's also weird is that the Intent data is always null, and the resultCode is always 0

Why is this happening? Shouldn't I only get a callback from OnActivityResult() once and also once? Shouldn't I get the result code I specify in setResult()?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680814/onactivityresult-executing-twice/49798484#49798484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after about 2 hours of debugging it seems

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Was the problem. Once I removed that everything worked as expected, which I guess makes sense. I can't clear the back stack and expect results to get returned correctly to the back stack I just cleared.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **etherton's answer**, also check whether your activity is declared as `singleTask` or not.

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` and check for `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your **called activity**. Remove this line and it will work as expected.

**Note:** If you really want your activity as `singleTask` then you have to handle your callbacks on your own.