# Intent returns null onActivityResult in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera-intent

Android 4.4 tested in Eclipse.

I've followed the lines as [developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/media/camera.html) said. So in my fragment I put:

```
public void tomarfoto() {
    // Check Camera
        if (MainActivity.if_cam) {

            // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

            // start the image capture Intent
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);               
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

After that, I set this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image saved to:\n" +data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that data intent is null and provokes this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1888, result=-1, data=null}
>   to activity {com.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I don't understand so much but apparently the onActivityResult is disconnected from the fragment who has called it so, it can't receive data results. How can I solve this?. The [launchMode="singleTask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512264/fragments-startactivityforresult-always-return-resultcode-0-and-intent-null-on-c?rq=1) or singleInstance is not my problem, I didn't settled this.

The pictures are saved properly in the directory held by fileUri. Help.